# Decrypt LUKS FDE Disk image

Tags: debian, backup, clonezilla, luks, fde

So, I screwed up my system with a risky dist --upgrade to the point where it won't boot. It's not the end of the world, because I have a recent backup, however there are a couple of files from the last few days I'd like to grab from the disk. However the disk is a 1TB SSD and with the hardware I have available mounting it on another machine is not directly feasible.

I have a full disk image created with Clonezilla. I know the LUKS FDE password because I set it, but I was wondering if there is a way for me to convert the FDE disk image to an unencrypted disk image so I can easily drop in and copy off the files I want without mounting the drive on another device with cryptfs etc?

Just for absolute clarity, this is about decrypting a *disk image* of an FDE drive to an *unencrypted image*, not mounting an encrypted drive on a live system.

Thanks.